# KOrganizer - add reminder by default

Tags: linux, debian, kde, organizer-software, pim

KOrganizer is nice, but I have to add a reminder manually every time I create an event.

When creating meetings in Outlook, the reminder is set to 15 minutes before event by default. I found that this works for me at least (and for many people I work with).

Is there some possibility to add 15 minutes reminder automatically to the event?

System:

KDE Plasma 5.8.6

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:    9.5
Codename:   stretch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but somehow not very intuitive to find:

> Having an alarm by default on events and to-dos can now be configured:
>   Menu -> Settings -> Configure KOrganizer -> Time and Date -> Default values -> Enable reminders for new events / to-dos.

Source: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68514#c9

[image]